# How to get rid of DNS Unlocker on Windows

Tags: virus-removal

I have found several online guides about removing DNS Unlocker but I haven't been able to complete any of the steps because no suspicious files, programs, etc. show up when I look for them. Google Chrome is very heavily infected with most pages opening new ad tabs whenever I click anywhere on the page.

I am using Windows XP SP3. I have had AVG Free for years which failed to prevent DNS Unlocker from being installed on my computer (one-two weeks ago).

Is there a program that can remove it or a series of steps that I can take manually?

Comment: I'm sorry but we are not virus tech support. Reformat and install from known good backups.

Comment: Windows XP? XP no longer gets security patches. Reformat and install from a Windows 10 or Linux USB.

Comment: @NeilSmithline, that's an answer, not a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no common guide to remove DNS Unlocker, but maybe on of the following might help:

- Check the extensions 'Add-ons' and disable any suspicious one.
- Clear browsing history and cached data.
- Clear Host cache in Google Chrome `chrome://net-internals/#dns`
- Check your `Programs and features` and remove DNS Unlocker from there.

Besides that, you need  to **upgrade your Windows**. Windows XP is out-dated and obsolete. Try to use more secure version of Windows OS.

Comment: Why do I **need** to upgrade Windows, i.e. buy a new computer? My current computer does everything I **need** it to already but can't run any later versions of Windows.

Comment: It's up to you but be informed that Windows XP is no longer getting patches, so it will be always vulnerable.

Answer (score -1):

Their website has a handy guide to remove it...which is hilarious. Anyway here's the [link](http://www.dnsunlocker.com/uninstall/)
As a side note. Some very simple googling turned this up on the first page...we are not really tech support so try Google first mate.

Comment: You should really provide a list of bullets points or important information or a summary of a link you provide so that if the link should ever stop existing, your answer is still valid. Link only answers(like this one) are not considered answers.